# Call constructor without object name

Tags: c++

In this code (assuming `T` can be any value type):

```cpp
T foo;
T(std::move(foo));  // <---
```

Is `T(std::move(foo))` the construction of an unnamed `T` from a `T&&`, or a C-style cast? I think both have the same effect, but I want to know what the expression means in the eyes of the compiler. In particular, it seems the expression `SomeType(someExpression())` in general can be parsed as a C-style cast.

Comment: It wil make an r-value reference for foo, forcing the compiler to select the move constructor for T.

Comment: The temporary (from the second construction) won't live long. Nevertheless, it will realize the side-effects of the constructor - e.g. "moving" the contents from `foo` (or whatever the move constructor of `T` dictates).

Comment: "C-style" casts are `(type) expression`, not `type (expression)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo The latter has the exact same semantics though, so it should probably be counted as a C-style cast.

Comment: @user17732522 It doesn't and shouldn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo They only differ in what can be parsed for `type`: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2.sentence-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what the expression means in the eyes of the compiler

Both mean the same thing.

The standard calls `(T)x` an ["Explicit type conversion (cast notation)"](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast), and `T(x)` an ["Explicit type conversion (functional notation)"](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv).

"C-style cast" is not an official term, and it's moot whether `T(x)` (with a single argument) counts as a C-style cast or not. IMO it does.